# Не могу добавить значение в существующий массив json через PHP. Ничего не помогает

Tags: php, json, decode

Ребята, всё перерыл. Сдают нервы.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть массив типа

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 666
    },
    "status": "ok",
    "timestamp": 1541259393211,
    "data": [{
        "issueDate": "2018-08-22",
        "repaymentDate": "2018-09-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 300,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2018-09-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2018-10-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2018-10-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2018-11-26",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2018-11-26",
        "repaymentDate": "2018-12-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2018-12-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-01-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-01-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-02-25",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-02-25",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-03-25",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-03-25",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-04-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-04-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-05-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-05-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-06-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-06-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-07-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-07-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-08-26",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-08-26",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-09-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-09-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-10-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-10-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-11-25",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-11-25",
        "repaymentDate": "2019-12-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2019-12-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-01-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-01-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-02-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-02-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-03-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-03-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-04-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-04-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-05-25",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-05-25",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-06-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-06-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-07-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-07-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-08-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-08-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-09-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-09-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-10-26",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-10-26",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-11-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }, {
        "issueDate": "2020-11-24",
        "repaymentDate": "2020-12-24",
        "principal": 0,
        "interest": 415500,
        "fee": 0,
        "penalty": 0,
        "rest": 3000000
    }]
}
```

Мне надо добавить новый ключ со значением 0 во все подмассивы.

Понимаю, что не сложно, но уже всё перепробовал. И unshift и slice и какие-то уже глупые варианты, но всё равно ничего не выходит.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Приложите пример, как уже пробовали

Comment: У вас не валидная json строка, добавьте в конец эти 2 символа `]}` , и тогда json_decode отлично работает

Comment: Anton, это я просто часть взял. Там он очень длинный просто весь.

Comment: Никита, вот пример - добавляю параметр в массив, но как только пытаюсь вывести в цикл - ничего не выходит.

Comment: foreach ($array34 as $zzz) {
    $zzz['PenaltyAsses3'] = '0';
}
    $array35 = json_encode($zzz);

print $array35;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($str, true);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['data']); $i++){
    $array['data'][$i]['newKey'] = 0;
}
```

Там где `newKey` вы должны добавить свой ключ.

ну и соответственно в переменной `$str` лежит ваша строка `json`

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Антон. Всё работает.
Моя ошибка - писал через $array33[$i]['data']['zzzzz']
Еще раз спасибо, и бонуса Вам к карме )

Comment: @Denisxyz, рад помочь)